Direction of normal vector in a boundary condition electromagnetic field problem
Is there any convention for the direction of normal vectors in boundary conditions related problems? Like the normal vector should be directed from region $1$ to region $2$ or from region $2$ to region $1$.
Consider the following problem.

5.40$\,$ A dielectric interface is defined by $4x+3y = 10 \ \text{m}$. The region including the origin is free space, where $\mathbf{D}_1 = 2 \, \mathbf{a}_x - 4 \, \mathbf{a}_y + 6.5 \, \mathbf{a}_z \ \text{nC/m}^2$. In the other region, $\varepsilon_{r2} = 2.5$. Find $\mathbf{D}_2$ and the angle $\theta_2$ that $\mathbf{D}_2$ makes with the normal.

In the problem above, the interfacing surface is $4x+3y=10$. The normal vector to this surface can have 2 directions: positive and negative. Which one should I take and why?

Choose one direction and stick with it as shown in Boundary conditions for electromagnetic fields
